# Debugging webpack dev server using a vs code in a remote docker container

Tags: docker, webpack, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm currently creating a boiler plate for react with typescript, one of the things I'd like to do is debug from within vs code however I'm having issues configuring webpack to debug since it's running inside a docker container. Ideally I'd like to debug from my local Chrome but as I'm inside a remote container I can't get the VS code debugger to open Chrome

My launch.json configuration so far:

```
{
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
        "url": "http://localhost",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "trace": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*"
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to run it though it says "Error processing "launch": Can't find Chrome - install it or set the "runtimeExecutable" field in the launch config.

Comment: Is there any particular reason it needs to run in Docker, or can you use a local Node installation?

Comment: It doesn't need to run inside docker, if I can get chrome to open on my local PC but have the node container listening with docker